# TFS over Virtual Private Network (VPN) over P2P

Tags: domain-name-system, vpn, team-foundation-server, p2p, ddns

*[Note: I know this is a sloppy shot! I just want to cure my understanding about the P2P mesh.]*

**Goal:** I need to make my partner access the Team Foundation Server running on my local LAN, via the Internet.

- **Method 1:** I push the project to some TFS hosting! - Fail (Reason: I need a private repository and its paid. Our project is not worth the money)
- **Method 2:** I purchase the VPN service! - Fail (Reason: Its paid. Our project is not worth the money)
- **Method 3:** I setup the DDNS for my local server - Considerable (Reason: Again it going to cost us few dollars but indeed very few in comparison to Method1 & Method2)
- **Method 4:** (imaginary) Considering the working of P2P network
  applications, if there is a VPN solution which works over the P2P and
  on top of which we could run TFS! - Excellent (Reason: Its free providing it is a possibility!)

Please enlighten me about the technology(s) in question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Honestly I think you're asking for a lot.

At a bear minumum, I would suggest you at least pony up for a static IP setup.  With that, you would then be able to open the port as mentioned above, however you're also going to want to make sure you protect the traffic with SSL.  So make sure your TFS site is published via SSL.  As for p2p VPN, the one that comes to mind is logmein.com, but it's not free.

Comment: Not the best answer i expected; which should give some insight about the "VPN as a P2P app", the technology itself. But still your answer gives a closure to this discussion. Thank you!

Comment: Like i said, i think logmein can do a p2p VPN.  Honestly though, if you're going to host anything with any kind of reliablity, you want a static IP.

Answer (score 1):

Are you aware of the [hosted TFS Preview](http://tfspreview.com)?
It is a TFS hosted by Microsoft.

Another option is to open a port and access TFS over the internet. You don't need VPN to do that.

Comment: Yes, I have applied for the invitation code. But not lucky thus far. Our local server is connected with DSL (non-static/shared ipaddressed) thats y i mentioned about DDNS.

Answer (score 0):

I've answered a similar question on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6412549/remote-access-to-team-foundation-server-2010/6414564#6414564), most DDNS services offer a free option. I use no-ip.com. It's worth setting up a free account to test drive the connection